# Using tag-helper validation for list items

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34732092/taghelper-validation-when-editing-a-list), which seems to cover exactly what I want to do, but for some reason the solution presented there doesn't work for me.

I have in my view the following:

```
@model ExerciseEditModel

@foreach (var item in Model.Rounds)
{
    <!-- bootstrap grid markup omitted -->
    <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
        <label asp-for="item.DurationEstimate"></label>
        <input asp-for="item.DurationEstimate" type="time" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <!-- bootstrap grid markup, and more form elements, omitted -->
}
```

which as far as I can tell corresponds exactly to how the solution in the linked question works, but I get a build error on the view because

> 'ExerciseEditModel' does not contain a definition for 'item' and no extension method 'item' accepting a first argument of type 'ExerciseEditModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

It seems that the scope of the `asp-for` helper doesn't notice the `foreach` loop - how can I make it work?

Comment: Occam's Razor question: Are you missing a `using` statement anywhere?

Comment: @krillgar Maybe, but in that case I don't know which `using` statement I am missing (or which ones I need). What should I look for?

Comment: I haven't done Core MVC, which is why I posed a question. Sorry I couldn't help more, but it looks like David G has what you need.

Comment: Your missing the leading `@` - i.e. `asp-for="@item.DurationEstimate"`, however this will not bind to your model when you subit and you need to use a `for` loop with `asp-for=Model[i].DurationEstimate"` - refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943)) for more explanation

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms#expression-names):

> The `asp-for` attribute value is a `ModelExpression` and the right hand side of a lambda expression. Therefore, `asp-for="Property1"` becomes `m => m.Property1` in the generated code which is why you don't need to prefix with `Model`. You can use the "@" character to start an inline expression and move before the `m.`

So you should prefix your expressions with an `@`:

```
@model ExerciseEditModel

@foreach (var item in Model.Rounds)
{
    <!-- bootstrap grid markup omitted -->
    <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
        <label asp-for="@item.DurationEstimate"></label>
        <input asp-for="@item.DurationEstimate" type="time" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <!-- bootstrap grid markup, and more form elements, omitted -->
}
```